# ROR + MySql Query - To Compare Single Value With Comma Separated values present in Single Column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails, I am trying one query for MySql - While searching data from DB related to hierarchy, I have to pass specific id on the table.

Table: Hierarchy

```
id | parent    | name
1  |           | Electronics
2  |    1      | iPhone
3  |    1      | Moto G ( Android )
4  |           | Clothes
5  |    4      | Kidz Wear
```

Table: Comments

```
id | hierarchy_id | value
1  |    1         | Best electronic products values in this store.
2  |    1,2       | iPhone is always best.
3  |    4         | Cotton Clothes - Cool
4  |    1,3       | MotoG with Android M - Paise wasool
5  |    4,5       | New Collection Good One ...
```

Here, when I tried to search data using hierarchy 1, then it will show only one record. Here I am not getting the way to fetch  remaining records, because if I select any parent hierarchy then CHILD data should be there.

And If I select any CHILD hierarchy, then system should return value only related to that CHILD, by escaping PARENT and SIBLINGS

Getting Right Now :-

```
$ select * from comments where hierarchy_id = 1;
id | hierarchy_id | value
1  |    1         | Best electronic products values in this store.
```

Expected Output has to be for hierarchy_id = 1 :-

```
$ select * from comments where **************************
id | hierarchy_id | value
1  |    1         | Best electronic products values in this store.
2  |    1,2       | iPhone is always best.
3  |    1,3       | MotoG with Android M - Paise wasool
```

Expected Output has to be for hierarchy_id = 3 :-

```
$ select * from comments where **************************
id | hierarchy_id | value
1  |    1,3       | MotoG with Android M - Paise wasool
```

Please suggest some thing ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `hierarchy_id` in the comments table, why don't you use it in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE hierarchy_id=1
```

Comment: Good Catch, typo change ... I will update my question.